# Assign a C# string to a ViewData, then pass the ViewData to the alert() to display an alert

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I have this JS function in my .cshtml file. I need to pass the string from the C# Object to a JavaScript variable so that I can display the ReceiverName as an alert. I am kinda new to ASP.NET so I'm not quite sure whether this is the best way as C# and JS will have to be used together. Does anyone know a better approach as I am quite lost? This is my 1st question here so please if there's any more info required I'll be glad to answer : )

```
function autoFillForeign(){
        @{
            string custID = (string)ViewData["customerID"];
            PayeeListDAL payeeContext = new PayeeListDAL();
            List<PayeeList> payeeList = payeeContext.GetAllPayeeList(custID);
            ViewData["name1"] = payeeList[0].ReceiverName;
            @: alert(@ViewData["name1"])
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is there any problem with the above code? If it's working, are you just asking if there's a better way? If it's not working, please tell us what the problem is

Comment: you could make an ajax request from js and keep all the C# logic in the controller.

Comment: Sorry about that I phrased the question wrongly. The above code only works to the point of setting the ReceiverName to the ViewData. But in the next line, the alert code does not display the name as an alert.

Comment: Ohh, thank you @Izzy for that idea. I will try that out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't quite get what you want to achieve but it is easy to pass values from C# to JavaScript. You can try out these approaches...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     function autoFillForeign(){
        var msg = "@msg";
        alert(msg);
     }
</script>
```

and the C# variable might be declared any where above that function like below:

```
@{
     string msg = "You are learning good";
 }
```

Sometimes you might even want to get a value from C# function into JavaScript function, its still the same approach.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   function autoFillForeign(){
      var msg = "@ShortenText(msg)";
      alert(msg);
   }
</script>
```

Your C# code might look something like below:

```
@functions{
    public string ShortenText(string txt)
    {

       return (txt.Length > 10)? txt.Substring(0, 10): txt;
    }
}
```

and your c# variable might be declared like

```
@{
   string msg = "I am not a new C# programmer; I started programming C# since 2016";
 }
```

Comment: Omgggg. Thank you so much, sir. It's working well. For context, I wanted to do a feature where it will get the list of payees from the database and autofill their information on a form when a payee is selected from the dropdown. Thank you once again.

Comment: You are welcome. you can contact me via inbox (ngutortsenongo@gmail.com) for more solutions if you need anything quite different from the above solution.